# Form.Hide not hiding form but ends Modal state Bug?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using a Modal form to block user activity while running a time consuming routine - one that typically takes 20 - 30 seconds.

To prevent seeing the "Excel not Responding message" my time consuming routine uses DoEvents. However, if I called this routine from a button on a normal form (modal or not) that had multiple other user-clickable objects on the same form, the use of DoEvents allows the user to click other buttons and run other code (eg Record navigation code) before the time consuming routine finishes - possible mayhem.

To avoid this, I put my time consuming routine into it's own modal form with no other clickable objects on it (except the red X button that is automatically included - that fires the QueryClose event)

To prevent the user clicking the X to close my modal form (before the time consuming routine finishes) I used the following code

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   Cancel = 1  ' Prevents User closing the form
End Sub
```

However, when that code is included, it prevents Form.Hide from closing the form BUT DOES terminate the modal blocking, and other code outside of the form can run.

A work around is easy enough, change the code in the QueryClose Event to the following

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   If Me.Tag <> "OK2EXIT" Then
      Cancel = 1
   End If
End Sub
```

and precede any call to Form.Hide with

```
Me.Tag = "OK2EXIT"
```

Just thought I'd post this here to save time for someone else

Comment: I don't think the QueryClose event gets triggered when the userform is hidden, does it?

Comment: You can use CloseMode to determine whether the user clicked on the Control menu (the red X).  See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/queryclose-event).

Comment: @domenic yes it does Ithat's how I discovered what my problem was I put a MsgBox in there

Comment: @domenic Thanks, CloseMode is more elegant :-)   Still a problem behaviour though isn't it ?

Comment: Interesting... In my testing, the QueryClose event doesn't get called when the userform is hidden.

Comment: I would suggest that you remove DoEvents from your time consuming routine, and then use [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html) example to run your routine and display a progress indicator.  However, replace DoEvents with the Repaint method of the UserForm object in the procedure called `progress`.  This way the user won't be able to move the userform or click on the red X to close it.

Comment: @Domenic Thanks for that additional suggestion, however, my own method works fine now that I know of this peculiar behavior. I'll tryout your suggestion next time I need something similar. Thanks again.